# Frequency plot with a node as reference in Proteus

Tags: analog, proteus, frequency-response

I'm trying to make a frequency plot in Proteus of an inverse adder amplifier.

This is the schematic:

[image]

The thing is that when I use the frequency plot properties editor to change the property "reference" it don't let me put the node "vin" as a reference, it only lets my put voltage sources as a reference. I want to make a bode plot of the circuit using as reference vin which is the signal I want to amplify.

Does anyone know a solution to this problem? I know how to do it in LTspice or Pspice, but I need to do it in Proteus.

Comment: I'm glad you added that you knew how to do it with other spice programs. Since I don't know proteus, I can't help. But it will be interesting to see how it's done.

Comment: Plot Vo/Vin is my best guess.